Highlight specific value from options in lightning-dual-listbox
I'm trying to find a way to highlight a specified option value in lightning-dual-listbox. My ultimate goal is to be able to jump to a matching value when pressing any letter from the keyboard. I've already tried using the event onKeyDown combined with the method focus(), but this method only highlights the first value. My second attempt was trying to query specific <option> to set aria-selected = "true" but I couldn't access any inner components of the lightning-dual-listbox.

How to achieve this? Thanks for your response.

Unfortunately, if you're using the standard component, the behavior is what it is. If you want to customize this behavior, you'll need to write your own component. You can start using the Dueling Picklist SLDS blueprint.
